# Почему в js последний индекс for each - remove?

Tags: javascript

Для работы с объектами в массиве решил попробовать for each (`for (const item in array) {}`), но столкнулся с проблемой - почему последний `item` не число, а слово `remove`? Вроде как понятно - в массиве больше нет индексов и он превращает `item` в `remove`, но почему именно так? Нельзя что-ли вместо этого сразу выйти из цикла?

[image: для тех, кто в ящике и любит минусовать вопрос]

Comment: Для массивов нужно использовать `for...of`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var array = [{},{},{},{}];
for (const item in array) console.log(item);
```

Где-то у Вас есть код, который делает вот так:

```js
Array.prototype.remove = function() { console.log("in remove"); };
var array = [{},{},{},{}];
for (const item in array) console.log(item);
```

Comment: Ой-ё, спасибо! А то уже думал, в чём дело...